# Pandas: merging two dataframes and retaining only common column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames and some column names are same and some are different. I want to make a merged dataframe which has only the common column names.

For instance

```
d1 = {'group' : ('A', 'B', 'C') ,  'names' : ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma') ,'num1': (1,2,3)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'group' : ('B', 'C', 'D',) , 'names' : ('Beta','Gamma','Delta') ,'num2': (4,5,6)}
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Now to make a dataframe which has only `group` and `names` but not `num1` and `num2`, I do this

```
L1=list(df1.columns)
L2=list(df2.columns)
L=list(set(L1).intersection(L2))

df=pd.merge(df1,df2, on=L,how='outer')

cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in L]
df=df.drop(cols,axis=1)
df
```

This works perfectly fine for me but I am sure there is a better way of doing it. I just think I would not have to use `set intersection`, `merge` and `list comprehension` to achieve this.

I would appreciate any thoughts on more elegant way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do a [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) instead of a `merge`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner', ignore_index=True)
```

The resulting output:

```
  group  names
0     A  alpha
1     B   beta
2     C  gamma
3     B   Beta
4     C  Gamma
5     D  Delta
```

Comment: This is perfect and cannot believe I missed this.